# Facebook Graph API error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm fairly new to Facebook's Graph API. 
I'm trying to use their Graph API Explorer to post a message to my Fan Page wall. I have the paramters setup like below:-

*Req Type:*   POST

*Post URI:*   https://graph.facebook.com/MY_APP_ID/feed

*Name Value:* { message : 'This is a test message' }

Obviously the access token is set-up automatically in the Explorer.

But for some reason I get the error **(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action** when I try to make the request.

I assume I've got to set something up somewhere, but can't find anything? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ - you likely don't have the correct permissions in your access token - most likely to be missing is `publish_stream`

Comment: I was really hoping someone wouldn't point me back to that horrible place, but thanks a lot. I'll have a read :)

Comment: Ok, I took a look and it seems Yes, I need to allow the extended permission **publish_stream**. I have looked at my Edit App Settings but cannot find anything, do you know how to change the permissions of the app?

Comment: You probably need to read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ - If you're just testing in the Graph API explorer, just select the checkbox for publish stream in the dialog that pops up when you click 'Get Access Token'

Comment: Looks like it's called publish_page now.

Comment: The <APP>/feed endpoint was also removed subsequent to this question being asked, so probably best to just go straight to the current documentation if you're having a similar issue